# Approach on solving limit equation systems and finding some f given assymptotes?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functional-equations, mathematical-modeling

This is a "reverse" question of [finding the asymptote of a function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote)

Recently, I am interested in doing some sort of modelling which involve equations of the form

$$@(t)=1-f(t)$$

where $f(t)$ is required to satisfy the following properties

$$1^*:\left\{\begin{matrix}f(0)=0 \\ \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}f(t)=1 \\\text{f(t) is not of the form g(t)+1 where}\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}g(t)=0
\end{matrix}\right. $$

That is, $@(t)$ is modelling the change of some quantity (e.g. population) that starts at some constant value and slowly decay to zero as time progresses. I am interested in finding $f$ that satisfy $1^*$ so that I can experiment on various decay behaviour.

I know the graphical solution to $1^*$ is basically any functions that passes through the origin and has an asymptote y=1 in the posive t direction and does not involve some other function shifted up by 1, for example the following (x is t but google does not allow plotting using t as a variable)
[image]

However, it may not be easy to obtain a graphical solution, or **even if at least one graphical solution can be found, (I have no idea how to) obtain the mathematical expression for them** for more general problems such as

$$2^*:\left\{\begin{matrix}\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}h(t)=c ,\text{where c}\in \mathbb{R} \text{and is given} \\ \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}[h(t)-k(t)]=0 ,\text{where k(t) is given}\\\lim_{t\rightarrow a}h(t)-\lim_{t\rightarrow b}h(t)=4,\text{where a,b}\in \mathbb{R} \text{and are given}\\\ln(\lim_{t\rightarrow a}h(t))=8, \text{where c}\in \mathbb{R} \text{and is given}
\end{matrix}\right. $$

Therefore:

> Q1. What are the common, **algorithmic or analytical** approaches in solving systems of limit equations?
>
> Q2. For the particular case where some **finite number of asymptote functions were given**, how to recover the original function and under what condition is the solution unique?
>
> Q3. How to obtain a mathematical expression from the graphical solutions to these problems?